# Setting One Drop Down after Selecting from Another

Tags: javascript, html

I have a couple select elements:

```
<select name="empID" onchange='setSupervisor(this);'>
    <option value="111" sid="222">Eric Employee</option>
    ...
</select>

<select name="supervisorID">
    <option value="333">Susie Supervisor</option>
    <option value="222">Stan Supervisor</option>
</select>
```

And a javascript function:

```
function setSupervisor(sender)
{
    ??
}
```

How can I set the supervisor dropdown after the user selects from the employee dropdown?  The tricky part here (at least to me) is having to use a custom sid and not the value from the employee dropdown.

Comment: Why aren't you using the value of `sid` as the option's value? Adding your own custom `sid` attribute isn't valid HTML (although you can still get its value using `getAttribute` on the `<option>` element).

Comment: I'm not using sid as the option's value because they are different numbers.  The value in "empID" is essentially the employee number and the "sid" is the supervisor ID.  If it is not valid HTML then I'll have to try another way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function setSupervisor(sender) {
    var selectedOption = sender.getElementsByTagName("option")[sender.selectedIndex];
    var sid = selectedOption.getAttribute("sid");

    var supervisorSelect = document.getElementsByName("supervisorID")[0];
    for (var i = 0, len = supervisorSelect.options.length, option; i < len; ++i) {
        option = supervisorSelect.options[i];
        if (option.value == sid) {
            option.selected = true;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Really? Worked perfectly in all browsers I tested (Firefox 3.5.7, IE 7, Chrome) for me. I added one dummy option to the first select so that it had two options and hence the onchange could fire.

Comment: You are right, it does work.  I had another type of issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var empID = document.getElementsByName("empID").item(0);
var supervisorID = document.getElementsByName("supervisorID").item(0); //This becomes a bit easier if you set an ID as well as a name in your HTML    
var index = empID.selectedIndex;
var sid = empID.options[index].getAttribute("sid");
for(var i=0; i<supervisorID.options.length; i++)
{
    if(supervisorID.options[i].value == sid)
    {
        supervisorID.selectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing "int i" to "var i" and then alert(supervisorID.selectedIndex) is always 0 no matter who is selected as an employee.

Comment: I edited it, based on Tim Down's answer above.  See if that works.  If not, after setting the sid, insert alert(sid) to see what value it gets.